# Auto-create navigation link to a node

Tags: 7, users, navigation

I use [RULES module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create a node (my custom content type) on user creation - so another words every user gets **ONE, UNIQUE** node when creating account.

Now I would like to have a navigation menu for users, where each user has a link to his own node. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Just as example, imagine we are talking about node as user profile. Each user gets one of those nodes on user creation and I want to have a navigation link to edit/view this node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this I wrote a module, which creates a node on user create. The node has an alias, which is the username. Code below:

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'article';
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->title = $edit['name'];
    $node->path = array(
        'alias' => $edit['name'],
    );
    $node->uid = $account->uid;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    node_save($node);
}
```

Additionally I used [MENU_TOKEN](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module, which allows to input tokens into title and path of menu links. So my new navigation link path is **[current-user:name]**, which links user's article to his profile.

**EDIT:** Of course in the example I used 'article' as content type, but in practice I use a custom content type. So if you want to use this code, make sure this line:

```
$node->type = 'article';
```

is adjusted as per requirements.